# Click event for a list of buttons with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can we write a click event in jquery for a list of buttons with same class name?
The html part is something like this

```
<a id="c1768" class="MyButton button " href="#" style="" name="c1768">Add to cart</a>
<a id="c1769" class="MyButton button " href="#" style="" name="c1769">Add to cart</a>
<a id="c1770" class="MyButton button " href="#" style="" name="c1770">Add to cart</a>
<a id="c1771" class="MyButton button " href="#" style="" name="c1771">Add to cart</a>
```

and script part is

```
$("MyButton button").click(function(){ //some event });
```

I want to do the event if any of the button is clicked, but the code is not working. Anyone help please.... Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".MyButton.button").click(function(){ //some event });
```

Comment: +1 for being the only answer (out of four) to recognise that he's testing both classes, and provide code that actually does so.

Comment: people are so fast nowadays :p

Answer (score 1):

you missed a dot shouldn't it be this:

```
$(".MyButton").click(function(){ //some event });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".MyButton.button").click(function(){ alert("Done!");});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BYbBr/

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
$(".MyButton").click(function(){ //some event });
```

Comment: The dot represents a class, since all your buttons have the same class this is all we need.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a dot to classnames (remember, jQuery selector are actually css selectors!).

Try this:

```
$(".MyButton .button").click(function(){ //some event });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong, use a dot(.) to define a class, also MyButton and button is on the same level:

```
$(".MyButton.button").click(function(){ //some event });
```

If you have events on multiple elements, you should consider using $.on(); See: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Tried this one but it does not worked in my case, don't know y, i am working on the Qcodo framework.